# python でオブジェクトが解放されたか確認する方法

Tags: python

特定のディレクトリにある大量のJSONファイルを読んで
それを加工してCSVに吐くようなバッチ処理があります

中の処理は JSON を読んだら何行かレコードを出力して
その後JSON自体は捨ててしまっていいはずで
実行途中にメモリ上に置く必要があるのはJSON１個分のはずで
JSONファイル１つ１つは大きくて 2MB でほとんどは数KBなのですが
このプログラムがなぜか 3GB のメモリを消費します

しかも全体で３０分ぐらいかかるバッチなんですが
実行中だんだんメモリが増えていってしまいます

概略でかくとこんな感じです

```
with open('xxx.csv', 'w') as wf:
  writer = csv.writer(wf)

  for json_file in directory_files:
    with open(json_file) as rf:
      json_data = rf.read()
      data = json.loads(json_data)

      csv_line = [data['key1'], data['key2'], ...] 
      # 実際はもっと複雑なことをしてますが data に対しては read only な処理です

      writer.writerow(csv_line)

      del data
      del json_data
      gc.collect()
```

他に例外処理とか終了通知とかログとかいろいろいれてるんですがファイル数に対して増える処理はこれだけです

1. del data を読んだ場合ネストしたハッシュの内側も全て削除してくれるのでしょうか
2. ソースコード上のどの変数でメモリが増えてるか調べる方法はないでしょうか

---

追記：

flush したり こまめに close open するのは効果なかったです

@profile をつけて行ごとのメモリ使用量を出力しながら実行したんですが
遅すぎて１GBとかまでいくまで確認できなかったんですが
最初２００MBぐらいからはじまって３００MBぐらいまでの間では
range(...) とか json.load とか writerows の中でときどきメモリが 0.1 とか 0.2 とか増えて定期的に一気に減ったりするので一時データやIOバッファの確保にメモリが使われてるだけみたいでした

Comment: 解放されたか、の前段階で、どこがどれだけ使っているかを[tracemalloc --- メモリ割り当ての追跡](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tracemalloc.html)とか[memory-profiler - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/)で調べられるのでは？ [\[python\]変数のメモリ消費量確認](https://qiita.com/kpasso1015/items/83062ac14c3c44907e5b), [Python: memory_profiler でプログラムのメモリ使用量を調べる](https://blog.amedama.jp/entry/2018/02/04/001950), [memory_profiler – Pythonコードのメモリ使用量を監視する](https://githubja.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler)

Comment: それはそれでメモリを食いそうですがpandasを使ってみるとか？ [Convert multiple JSON files to CSV Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-multiple-json-files-to-csv-python/), [How to convert multiple nested JSON files into single CSV file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68702422/9014308)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問に書いてあるコードにはメモリ使用量を増やす要素は見当たりません。
確認するコードを書いてみました。

```py
import csv
import json

NUMBER_OF_FILES = 10_000
NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 10

directory_files = [f'{i}.json' for i in range(NUMBER_OF_FILES)]

for f in directory_files:
    with open(f, 'w') as w:
        json.dump({f'key{k}': random.randint(0, 1000000) for k in range(NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)}, w)

with open('xxx.csv', 'w') as wf:
    writer = csv.writer(wf)

    for json_file in directory_files:
        with open(json_file) as rf:
            json_data = rf.read()
            data = json.loads(json_data)

            csv_line = [data[f'key{i}'] for i in range(NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)]

            writer.writerow(csv_line)
```

ここで`NUMBER_OF_FILES`や`NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS`を**変えても、メモリ使用量が増えていくようなことは起こりません**。
確認してみてください。
（こちらで確認したのは Python 3.8.12 macOS です）

質問に書かなかったコードの側に使用量が増える原因（オブジェクトを参照したままにするような箇所）があるのでしょう。

---

(追記)

> 1. del data を読んだ場合ネストしたハッシュの内側も全て削除してくれるのでしょうか

そもそもdelは「名前をオブジェクトから解放する」文であって、オブジェクトを解放する文ではありません。前提が間違っているように思います。

> 2. ソースコード上のどの変数でメモリが増えてるか調べる方法はないでしょうか

例えば

```py
from sys import getsizeof
from collections.abc import Mapping, Container

def deep_getsizeof(o, ids):
    """Find the memory footprint of a Python object

    This is a recursive function that drills down a Python object graph
    like a dictionary holding nested dictionaries with lists of lists
    and tuples and sets.

    The sys.getsizeof function does a shallow size of only. It counts each
    object inside a container as pointer only regardless of how big it
    really is.

    :param o: the object
    :param ids:
    :return:
    """
    d = deep_getsizeof
    if id(o) in ids:
        return 0

    r = getsizeof(o)
    ids.add(id(o))

    if isinstance(o, str) or isinstance(o, bytes):
        return r

    if isinstance(o, Mapping):
        return r + sum(d(k, ids) + d(v, ids) for k, v in o.items())

    if isinstance(o, Container):
        return r + sum(d(x, ids) for x in o)

    return r
```

みたいな関数を書いて、
`print(deep_getsizeof([1,2,3,4], set())) # => 200`
`print(deep_getsizeof([1,1,1,1], set())) # => 116`
みたいに使えます。

（https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609 のコードをPython3向けに書き直したもの）

Answer (score 0):

表題の質問に対する回答にはなりませんが、

> 実行途中にメモリ上に置く必要があるのはJSON１個分のはずで JSONファイル１つ１つは大きくて 2MB でほとんどは数KBなのですが
> このプログラムがなぜか 3GB のメモリを消費します しかも全体で３０分ぐらいかかるバッチなんですが
> 実行中だんだんメモリが増えていってしまいます

これについて言えば、`wf` を open し続けているので、大量の JSON ファイルを書き出す総量分に相当するメモリーを占拠し続けるのではないですか？

```
with open('xxx.csv', 'w') as wf:
    writer = csv.writer(wf)
```

この部分を for ブロックの外側ではなくて、for の内側で**追記モードで**都度、オープン、書き出し、クローズするようにしたらどうでしょうか？

```
for json_file in directory_files:
    with open(json_file) as rf, open('xxx.csv', 'a') as wf:
        ...
        writer = csv.writer(wf)
        writer.writerow(csv_line)
        ...
```

追記モードでもファイル全体と同じサイズのメモリーを消費するのだとしたら、結局大差ないかもしれませんが……。（オープンクローズの繰り返しにより、却って GC がより頻発に発生するだけかも？）

Answer (score 0):

CSVファイルの出力がメモリにバッファリングされている気がします。
フラッシュしてはいかがでしょうか。

```
wf.flush()
```